# SQL: Combine values per ID into one variable

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

I have following table:

```
ID  Var   
01  Value1 
01  Value2    
01  Value3    
02  Value4
02  Value2    
02  Value3 
03  Value1
03  Value2
```

and would like to convert it into following format:

```
ID  Vars
01  Value1, Value2, Value3
02  Value4, Value2, Value3
03  Value1, Value2
```

What SQL command can I use to do this?

Comment: look at `group_concat`.

Comment: `SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(Var) AS Vars FROM yourTable GROUP BY ID`

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `group_concat()`:

```
select id, group_concat(var separator ', ') as vars
from t
group by id;
```

Three notes:

- You change the separator using the `SEPARATOR` keyword; the default is comma without a space.
- If you care about the ordering, then use `ORDER BY var`.
- If you want to remove duplicates, then use `group_concat(distinct var)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `group_concat`, e.g.

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(Var)
FROM table
GROUP BY ID;
```

Here's the documentation for [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).